# What's the timezone of 3-Hourly TRMM Data?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, trmm

**I am using google earth engine just to print the timestamp here of TRMM Data. I am using the geometry of a part of Chennai which is in India.**

```js
// Filtering Data with Date and Geometry
var Data1 = TRMM.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2013-04-09', '2014-04-10');

// Printing Timestamp
print('TRMM Metadata', Data1.first().date());
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(geometry,{color: 'FF0000'},"Chennai");
```

**My question what exactly the printed time does indicate (with respect to UTC (GMT) or Local Time Zone (IST) ).**

just in case if you need the import

**IMPORTS:**

```js
var TRMM = ee.ImageCollection("TRMM/3B42"),
geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[80.26491619216495, 13.08801893465061],
      [80.26422954665713, 13.077652181027775],
      [80.28002239333682, 13.08166516962143]]]);
```

**I am using google earth engine only to print the timestamp here of TRMM Data and not anyway related to my question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current [TRMM documentation](https://pmm.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/document_files/3B4XRT_doc_V7.pdf):

> The *time zone* for this data set is Universal Coordinated Time (UTC, also known as GMT or Z).